# Make a Firefox and Chrome extension with one code base

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, wrapper

I am wondering if there is a language / specification out there where you can write a single code base and have that compiled into a Chrome and Firefox extension respectively.

I know that the design philosophy is very different but it seems like it would be fairly easy to at least create a limited use case where code redundancy could be reduced.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing.  If it's essentially a content script, then you only need a little bit of browser specific files to make it happen.  If you're needing chrome.* apis or the corresponding ideas from Firefox, it would make things more complicated.

Comment: There are cross browser extension frameworks.  But that would be getting into software recommendations, which we don't do on this site.  What do you want your extension to do?  Get it working for Chrome and Firefox.  What do you need help combining?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Kango - cross-browser extension framework - [Kango](http://kangoextensions.com/).

It is free and simple. I think this is what you want.

Comment: Correction: _"Kango is free for open source non-profitable projects. 
To learn more about the commercial license please contact us."_

Comment: See, I knew there had to be something.

Answer (score 0):

Found this too: BabelExt is open source beta cross browser extension framework.

http://babelext.com/